# Creating a global struct for multiple source files

Tags: c

I have a common header file for multiple source files in a C project. I want a certain struct instance:

```
typedef struct
{
    char username[255];
    char password[255];
} Configuration;

Configuration config;
```

To be available for all source files, and any changes made to it in any of the source files, should affect all others. How is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your header file you declare the config variable as extern:

```
extern Configuration config;
```

And in one, and only one, source file you define that variable like so:

```
Configuration config;
```

Comment: What about it's initialization?

Comment: @vinnylinux However you like. Use `Configuration config = { "this", "that"};` Or create a function that initializes the global variable, which you call once in your program, or do `config.username = "this";` somwhere. By default "global" variables are zero initialized, i.e. your two strings will be empty strings.