# making a global struct pointer available to multiple source files

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scope, extern

I have a struct declared in a header file called `h1.h` that included in two source files, `c1.c` and `c2.c`.

```
typedef struct
{
    char binary_filename[256];
}programming;
```

I want to create two variables of this struct, `device1` and `device2` and then declare two pointers to each of these variables, `programmingPtr1` and `programmingPtr2`.

I want to be able to access the member, `binary_filename` of a instance in each of the source files.

I'm confused as to where I should declare these variables and pointers.

Should I declare the variables as `extern` in the header?

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970288/creating-a-global-struct-for-multiple-source-files) but it doesn't deal with pointers to variables.

Could someone advise please as to the best method?

Comment: You define the variable in one of the `C` files and declare it as `extern` in the other one (or in the header.. depending on your design)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use variables in multiple source files, you'll need to **declare** them in a header file that all relevant sources include, then you **define** them in exactly one source file.

So your header would have:

```
extern programming device1;
extern programming device2;
extern programming *programmingPtr1;
extern programming *programmingPtr2;
```

Then in *one* source file, you would have:

```
programming device1 = { "filename1" };
programming device2 = { "filename2" };
programming *programmingPtr1 = &device1;
programming *programmingPtr2 = &device2;
```

Comment: thanks I tried that, I am getting an `undefined reference to `programmingPtr1'` in the source file? Any ideas?

Comment: @articsol You need to link the two files together.  With FCC that would be `gcc -o program file1.c file2.c`

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating any instances - they are just two separate structures in the global scope. Same is with the pointer. You just need to inform the compiler that the object is defined somewhere else using keyword `extern`. Of course you need to have your typedef as well.

The actual "connection" between defined extern object and the physical objext will done by the linker.